# How to calculate nth degree of function composition?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Lets say I have $f(x)=x+a$ and $g(x)=x+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants.
And I have to find $(gf)^n (X)$. Here I am confused with $(gf)^n$ part.

Is it correct to do it this way: $$$$
1) $f(x)=x+a$  $$$$
2) $g(f(x))=x+a+b$ $$$$
3) $f(g(f(x)))=x+2a+b$ $$$$
... $$$$
n) $g(f(...))=....$ $$$$

Comment: I haven't seen that notation before. Is it $g^n(f^n(x))$?

Comment: I also see it for the first time, and couldn't find on web what does it mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text suggests that juxtaposition and exponents refer to function composition. Let $h:=g\circ f$. Then $h:\> x\mapsto x+a+b$ is  translation by the amount $a+b$, hence $h^{\circ n}$ is translation by $n(a+b)$:
$$h^{\circ n}:\quad x\mapsto x+n(a+b)\ .$$
If, however, the term $(gf)(x)$ denotes the ordinary product $$g(x)f(x)=x^2+(a+b)x+ab=:p(x)$$
then $(gf)^n$ has to be interpreted as
$$(gf)^n(x)=p^n(x)=\bigl(x^2+(a+b)x+ab\bigr)^n\ .$$
Ask your professor which of the two (s)he had in mind.

(The notation $h^{\circ n}$ is widely used in cases that might lead to a misunderstanding.)

Comment: Ok, tq for the reply. Since I haven't seen this notation before I have assumed it is function composition